# weblogic wlst findService NameError

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I have the following wlst script:

```
import wlstModule
from com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration import SessionManagementMBean
from com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration import ALSBConfigurationMBean
from com.bea.wli.config import Ref

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to read a binary file
#=======================================================================================
def readBinaryFile(fileName):
    file = open(fileName, 'rb')
    bytes = file.read()
    return bytes

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to create an arbitrary session name
#=======================================================================================
def createSessionName():
    sessionName = String("SessionScript"+Long(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString())
    return sessionName

def getSessionManagementMBean(sessionName):
    SessionMBean = findService("SessionManagement", "com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.SessionManagementMBean")
    SessionMBean.createSession(sessionName)
    return SessionMBean


SessionMBean = None 
importJar='C:\\OSB_PROJECT.jar'
theBytes = readBinaryFile(importJar)
sessionName = createSessionName()
SessionMBean = getSessionManagementMBean(sessionName)
```

The result is an error:

> wls:/offline> execfile('C:\script.py') Traceback (innermost last):
>   File "", line 1, in ?   File "C:\script.py", line 31, in ?
>   File "C:\script.py", line 22, in get SessionManagementMBean
>   NameError: findService

How can I fix this?

Comment: May be you are executing wrong part of script/module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you ever connecting to your server and accessing the domain runtime? You should be doing something like the following:

```
connect("weblogic", "weblogic", "t3://localhost:7001")
domainRuntime()

# obtain session management mbean to create a session.
# This mbean instance can be used more than once to
# create/discard/commit many sessions
sessionMBean = findService(SessionManagementMBean.NAME,SessionManagementMBean.TYPE)
```

See more here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13171_01/alsb/docs25/javadoc/com/bea/wli/sb/management/configuration/SessionManagementMBean.html